# Bootstrap: stretching navbar input box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to modify an example bootstrap navbar (jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h9x3qvpd/1/). Right now I've hardcoded the width to get some stretching, but this obviously ruins the responsiveness.

Is there a way to get the input element to stretch all the way across the screen? My code is below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:620px">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Why not have the width be a percentage of the parent div?

Comment: @pmac89: Can you please show me on the fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do change one line from:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:620px">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:80%">
```

Or however big you want it to take up.

Edit: Though the best would be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:100%">
```

My [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nup6bLh/).