# How to stretch the searchbox in a navbar using bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm new to front-end development and I am trying to design a page that also has a searchbox(here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/he40tr9z/1/). I copied the navbar component from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/ and did some minimal modifications to make the searchbox appear before the nav items and to right align the nav items. Now I want the searchbox to stretch from the navbar-brand to the nav items but I can't seem to do that. I've searched the web and all the solutions I've found were for previous versions of Bootstrap which when applied to Bootstrap 5 don't work.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Brand image" width="180" height="52"></img></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <form class="d-flex ms-auto me-auto">
                    <input class="form-control" id="searchbox" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"></input>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 d-flex">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is the code from my css file:

```
#searchbox{
    width:  100%;
}
```

I put `width:100%` cause I saw it in this solution [Bootstrap: stretching navbar input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869558/bootstrap-stretching-navbar-input-box) but it doesn't work for Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use w-100 on the containing form...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="//via.placeholder.com/180x52" alt="Brand image" width="180" height="52"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <form class="d-flex ms-auto me-auto border w-100">
                <input class="form-control" id="searchbox" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 d-flex">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/W6MU0PKM89)